# What's the syntax of Python Simple Statements?

Tags: python

I read this documentation:
http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html

Now, I want to create statements like it describes. For example, a statement that concat a multiple assert and print statements. The syntax is unclear. How would I use the `::=` operator?

I will be grateful for a clear example.

Comment: By syntext do you mean syntax?

Comment: There is no `::=` operator in python.
It's part of the meta-grammer used to define a grammer element in terms of other grammer elements.

Comment: `::=` is not a Python operator, it is part of the definition of the language syntax, meaning "is defined to be".

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you say you want to create a statement.  I think you mean you want to create a function that will perform multiple asserts and print, but I'm not sure.  Could you clarify what you're hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are confusing the Python grammar reference with examples of actual Python code. The sections with `::=` are formally describing the structure of Python statements in [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). The other examples show actual Python code, and how the formal grammar looks in practice.

For example, the grammar element `assert_stmt` has the form:

```
assert_stmt ::= "assert" expression ["," expression]
```

This describes the structure of an actual Python assert statement, for example:

```
assert (2 + 2 == 4), "The world is ending!"
```

The quoted elements in the grammar, called *terminals*, appear literally in the Python syntax. These include, for example, the `assert` keyword and the comma. The unquoted parts refer to other grammar elements, called *nonterminals*; for example, `expression` corresponds to a Python expression returning a value. Grammar elements in brackets `[]` denote optionality, so `expression ["," expression]` refers to a comma-separated list of one or two expressions.